# Equation of a Circle (Complex Eq.)

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, circles

I am working through a calculation and it says that when $\omega$ is close to $\omega_L$, the second term below describes a circle with a diameter of $d = \frac{2 \kappa}{1 + \kappa}$. Can someone help me see why this is true?

$$\Gamma=\Gamma_0 \left(1-\frac{2\kappa}{1+\kappa}\frac{1}{1+i Q_L 2 \frac{\omega - \omega_L}{\omega_0}} \right)$$

Comment: Can you explain what each variable means... for instance the term $\Gamma_0(\cdot)$ can either be interpreted as a function $\Gamma_0$ or just a constant $\Gamma_0$ multiplied by something. But for now if $\omega$ is close to $\omega_L$ then $\Gamma \approx \Gamma_0 \left(1-\frac{2\kappa}{1+\kappa}\right)$

Comment: $\Gamma_0$ is a constant multiplying the term in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\theta=Q_L2\frac{\omega-\omega_L}{\omega_0}<<1$$
$$\frac{1}{1+i\theta}=\frac{1-i\theta}{1+\theta^2}\approx 1-i\theta\approx \cos\theta-i\sin\theta=e^{-i\theta}$$
$$\therefore \frac{2\kappa}{1+\kappa}\frac{1}{1+i\theta}\approx \frac{2\kappa}{1+\kappa}e^{-i\theta}$$

Comment: This is a very nice analysis, but it suggests that the radius is $\frac{2\kappa}{1+\kappa}$ instead of the diameter. Perhaps there is a mistake in the calculation I'm working through?

Comment: Yeah you're right. Sorry, I have no idea..